# Getting the length of time between start and end of orchestrator function

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have an an orchestrator function that has a few `CallHttpAsync`'s within it.  I am doing some load testing and trying to isolate how long, on average, the orchestrator function takes to complete.  I'm having trouble getting to a query that will give me this in an ideal format.

I currently have this:

```
union traces
| where customDimensions.Category == 'Host.Triggers.DurableTask'
| extend instanceId = customDimensions['prop__instanceId']
| extend state = customDimensions['prop__state']
| extend isReplay = tobool(tolower(customDimensions['prop__isReplay']))
| extend sequenceNumber = tolong(customDimensions["prop__sequenceNumber"])
| where isReplay != true
| where operation_Name == 'O_EnrollInCanvas'
| sort by timestamp desc, sequenceNumber desc
| sort by timestamp asc, sequenceNumber asc
| project timestamp, instanceId, sequenceNumber, state, operation_Name, message
```

Using these results I could take over to excel and figure it out; however, I'm trying to see if I can get the result directly from an insights query.  Here is an example of the results.  You can see the `instanceId` which can be used to get the **Started**, **Scheduled**, and **Completed** time
[image]

Using the highlighted instanceId from the screenshot, my ideal result would be something like this:

```
instanceId | StartedTimestamp | CompletedTimestamp
14afcd0d7fcb43a3a94e4869c81f9047 | 2/20/2023, 11:38:33.381 AM | 2/20/2023, 11:38:34.827 AM
```

Update; I *think* this can be accomplished using the `join`:

```
let FunctionTraces = traces | where operation_Name == 'O_EnrollInCanvas';
union FunctionTraces
| where customDimensions.Category == 'Host.Triggers.DurableTask'
| extend instanceId = customDimensions['prop__instanceId']
| extend state = customDimensions['prop__state']
| extend isReplay = tobool(tolower(customDimensions['prop__isReplay']))
| extend sequenceNumber = tolong(customDimensions["prop__sequenceNumber"])
| where isReplay != true
| where state == 'Started'
| join (FunctionTraces
        | where customDimensions['prop__state'] == 'Completed'
        | extend instanceId = customDimensions['prop__instanceId']
        | project CompletedTimestamp = timestamp, CompletedInstance = instanceId)
        on $right.instanceId == $left.instanceId
| where operation_Name == 'O_EnrollInCanvas'
| sort by timestamp desc, sequenceNumber desc
| sort by timestamp asc, sequenceNumber asc
| project timestamp, instanceId, sequenceNumber, state, operation_Name, message
```

However, with the current query I'm getting the error `join: Invalid entities used as join attributes. When using equality expressions, entities should be used by specifying its source $left or $right.`

Answer (score 0):

Just needed a little finessing:

```
let FunctionTraces = traces | where operation_Name == 'O_EnrollInCanvas';
union FunctionTraces
| where customDimensions.Category == 'Host.Triggers.DurableTask'
| extend instanceId = tostring(customDimensions['prop__instanceId'])
| extend state = customDimensions['prop__state']
| extend isReplay = tobool(tolower(customDimensions['prop__isReplay']))
| extend sequenceNumber = tolong(customDimensions["prop__sequenceNumber"])
| where isReplay != true
| where state == 'Started'
| join (FunctionTraces
        | where customDimensions['prop__state'] == 'Completed'
        | extend instanceId = tostring(customDimensions['prop__instanceId'])
        | project CompletedTimestamp = timestamp, appId, instanceId)
        on $left.instanceId == $right.instanceId
| extend secondsElapsed = datetime_diff('second', CompletedTimestamp, timestamp)
| extend minutesElapsed = datetime_diff('minute', CompletedTimestamp, timestamp)
| extend elapsed =  strcat(tostring(minutesElapsed), ' minute(s), ', tostring(secondsElapsed), ' second(s)')
| project Start = timestamp, Completed = CompletedTimestamp, elapsed, instanceId, sequenceNumber, state, operation_Name, message 
| where operation_Name == 'O_EnrollInCanvas'
| sort by Start desc, sequenceNumber desc
| sort by Start asc, sequenceNumber asc
```

Results in:
[image]